# how to set camera white balance using rgb color using with seekbar

Tags: android, camera, seekbar

Camera parameter setting dynamically, if change seek bar value at that time increase and decrease value of white balance. change white balance value change programmatically.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35886771/2078074). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
mWhiteBallance.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            Camera.Parameters param;
            param = camera.getParameters();
            // modify parameter
            Log.d(" Progress ", " >> > > >>> " + i);

            if (i == 0) {
                param.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_INCANDESCENT);
            } else if (i == 10) {
                param.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_FLUORESCENT);
            } else if (i == 20) {
                param.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
            } else if (i == 30) {
                param.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_DAYLIGHT);
            } else if (i == 40) {
                param.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT);
            }

            camera.setParameters(param);
            Log.i(" Progress ", "Supported White Balance Modes:" + param.getWhiteBalance().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```