# camera2 API - set white balance but get green picture

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have an issue when getting the previous color temperature of the picture taken and seting on the next picture using camera2 API.

```
if ( nbOfPict > 0 ){
       builder.set( CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF );
       builder.set( CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CameraMetadata.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_TRANSFORM_MATRIX );
       builder.set( CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM, characteristics.get( CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM1 ) );
       builder.set( CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature );
}
```

and on the capture result

```
if ( nb == 0 ) {
       colorTemperature = result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS);
}
```

but after the second picture taken, the result picture became green like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQkJk.jpg) on Huawei only, I don't know why. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439159/camera2-api-set-custom-white-balance-temperature-color) also have green picture but doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use the value of COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM from CaptureResult like you do with COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS instead of using SENSOR_CALIBRATION_TRANSFORM1; the latter is meant for processing RAW images, not for using as a valid COLOR_CORRECTION_TRANSFORM.

You could also consider simply locking AWB until you're done capturing images.

Comment: I couldn't get the colour correction transformation to work, but the AWB lock works, I wonder if my application will change the white balance before the AWB lock and after the first photo as mention in the documentation.

Comment: Eddy Talvala once again you saved me!